# How can I make these buttons stack on top of each other centered after a window-width change?

Tags: html, css

[I have a container](http://jsfiddle.net/je821vz9/3/) that usually has a `width` of 400px. When the screen gets smaller, its `width` is reduced to 300px. These two values are static and don't change.

I have 3 buttons within this container. At the wider width, I'd like to have 2 side by side and the 3rd one on the line below. All of them are centered.

[image: buttons in wide width]

When the container is compressed, I'd like to have all the buttons stack on top of each other centered.

[image: buttons stacked & centered in narrow width]

I can get it at the wide width but can't get it at the narrow width.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="varied-width">
    <div class="pg-sp2 prompt-gate">Did you find what you were looking for?
        <div class="pg-3-buttons">
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(1)">Yes</button>
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(0)">No, you suck</button>
        </div>
        <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(2)">No, I need help.</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    width: 400px;
}

.prompt-gate {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #fefab1;
    border: 1px solid #ffd532;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.prompt-gate-button {
    background-color: #0E80B4;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 72px;
    border: none;
    margin: 15px 25px;
    outline: none;
    font-style: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pg-3-buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
    .pg-3-buttons .prompt-gate-button {
        float: left;
    }

.pg-sp2 button {
    margin: 5px 15px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

.pg-sp2 > button {
}

.small-width {
    width: 300px;
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/je821vz9/10/

Comment: What do you mean doesnt exist? Are you going to shrink `varied-width` down with a @media query? Because this is still doable.

Comment: In the real application, the width of the container is changed via javascript. I updated the fiddle accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/je821vz9/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow figured it out... removed floats and moved around the button HTML so that they were all in the same container.

http://jsfiddle.net/je821vz9/19/

```
<div id="varied-width">
    <div class="pg-sp2 prompt-gate">Did you find what you were looking for?
        <div class="pg-3-buttons">
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(1)">Yes</button>
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(0)">No, you suck</button>
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(2)">No, I need help.</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
body {
    width: 400px;
}
.prompt-gate {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #fefab1;
    border: 1px solid #ffd532;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.prompt-gate-button {
    background-color: #0E80B4;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 72px;
    border: none;
    margin: 15px 25px;
    outline: none;
    font-style: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.pg-3-buttons {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.pg-sp2 button {
    margin: 5px 15px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Nice, I was playing with the same thing, but hadn't quite gotten it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Used flex layout instead: http://jsfiddle.net/je821vz9/7/

Added this to .prompt-gate style and then cleaned up some of the conflicting HTML and CSS.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Flex looks like it it is only with IE11 up... I need older capability. Otherwise this works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and have the viewport size decided on how to display the elements.

I added the following css to your body:

```
body { 
  max-width:400px;
  min-width:300px;
}
```

We can then add a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to adjust how the items are laid out:

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  div.pg-3-buttons .prompt-gate-button {
    display:block;
    float:none;
  }
}
```

See an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/je821vz9/17/) of your example and scale down the width of your browser to see the items pop in to place at 300px.

Comment: This almost works but it seems to only change if the window gets too small (entire `<body>`?) The buttons should depend on the container's width that they are in rather than the overall body width. See http://jsfiddle.net/je821vz9/18/ and press the "toggle width" button

Comment: Ah.  Was playing around with this before your edit.  Media queries work based on viewport size, not individual element size.